# How do I normalise a URL from a folder to a subdomain?

Tags: apache, htaccess

I have a mybb forum hosted at a folder inside my site, which can also be accessed via a subdomain.
I would like to configure it so that if someone would enter the folder it would automatically be redirected to the subdomain:

http://www.antinovaordemmundial.com/mybb/

to

http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com

Once you enter in the forum using the folder URL, any other link will automaticaly redirect to the subdomain, with the exception of the main page ( http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com )

My htaccess is as follows:

```
 # Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
  #RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301
 RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Forum-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Topico-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Anuncio-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Usuario-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Calendario-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Evento-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /misc.php?google_seo_error=404
 <IfModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add:

```
Redirect 301 /mybb/ http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com
```